# Pass an object as function parameter in powershell for GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I write GUI. And cannot pass the TextBox argument with the type TextBox.

Here is the code:

```
function CreateBrowserFolder {
   parram($Mainform, $TextBox)

   $IinitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
   $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
   $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
   $OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = $false
   $Response = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() #Response return OK or Cancel
   if ($Response -eq 'OK') {
       $TextBox.Text = $OpenFileDialog.Filename
   }
}

function AddActionToButton {
    param($Button, $Function)

    try {
        $Button.Add_Click({$Function})
    } catch {
        write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}


function CreateGUI {
    $SelectFileButton= CreateButton -Mainform $Mainform -TextValue "Select File" -LocationW 370 -LocationH 40 -SizeW 90 -SizeH 30

    AddActionToButton -Button $SelectFileButton -Function $FunctionToPass
}
```

Previously I had a problem to pass `$TextBox` as an argument. I solved this one adding the `[CmdletBinding]` before param and need to force the PSObject.

You can check the code below.

```
function CreateBrowserFolder {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param([PSObject] $TextBox)

   $IinitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
   $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
   $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
   $OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = $false
   $Response = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() #Response return OK or Cancel
   if ($Response -eq 'OK') {
       $TextBox.Text = $OpenFileDialog.Filename
   }

   return $TextBox
}

function AddActionToButton {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($Button, [PSObject] $TextBox)

    try {
        $RetVal = $Button.Add_Click({$Function -param $ValueParam}.GetNewClosure())
    } catch {
        write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    
    return $RetVal
}


function CreateGUI {
    $SelectFileButton= CreateButton -Mainform $Mainform -TextValue "Select File" -LocationW 370 -LocationH 40 -SizeW 90 -SizeH 30

    $RetVal = AddActionToButton -Button $SelectFileButton -TextBox
}
```

Now I would like to extract the returned value by the given function in parameter in the `Add_Click` to $RetVal in the `AddFunctionToButton`.

If someone can help me thx

Comment: You never call `CreateBrowserFolder`? Where is `CreateButton` defined?

Comment: Yes I call `CreateBerowserFolder` as $FunctionToPass. I don't specify this function because it can be an other one. CreateButton is an other function in my file to create a Button.

Comment: Note: there's some typos in your code (`[CmdletBinding]` should be `[CmdletBinding()]`, `parram` should be `param`).  I assume that's just a mistake when posting the question, but mentioning in case that's your actual code?

Comment: Yes sorry juist a bad copy. I correct that thx